# Como forçar que uma página abra na sempre horizontal?

Tags: javascript, html

Minha página apresenta bugs quando visualizada na vertical, além disso ela é 
melhor visualizada na horizontal.

É possível forçar para que uma página abra sempre na horizontal em dispositivos móveis?
E permaneça fixa na horizontal.

Comment: Não entendi, dê mais detalhes? Ou print?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você quer desativar o recurso do dispositivo móvel que reorienta a visualização de acordo com a posição do mesmo? **Isso não é possível.**

---

O que você pode fazer é adaptar o seu layout para que apareça "sem bugs" na posição vertical.

Você pode determinar uma largura mínima usando CSS:

```
#conteudo {
    min-width: 640px;
}
```

Você pode usar *media queries*, um recurso do CSS para aplicar determinadas regras de acordo com características do visualizador, tornando o *design* da página "*responsivo*".

Fica difícil ajudar mais sem vermos alguma imagem ou código (de preferência ambos).

---

Outra coisa meio doida que você pode fazer é usar JavaScript para verificar se está na vertical (altura > largura) e, se estiver, aplicar uma classe CSS para rotacionar a tela em 90 graus. Desse modo, o usuário será "forçado" a manter o dispositivo na horizontal para ver o site "de pé".

Classe CSS:

```
.virado {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

JavaScript (com jQuery):

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    if (screen.height > screen.width) {
        $('body').addClass('virado');
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('virado');
    }
});
```

Comment: Boa ideia a "coisa meio doida". Mas deve dar uma flickada na hora que girar da vertical pra horizontal, não?

Comment: O jeito é experimentar para ver. Eu nunca fiz isso - apenas dei uma pesquisada e vi sugestão similar no SO em inglês: [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975387/mobile-site-force-landscape-only-no-auto-rotate) e [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009743/jquery-mobile-lock-orientation). Eles sugerem também, ao invés de rotacionar, apenas exibir um aviso que o site "só funciona na horizontal".

Comment: Funcionou. Mas, só precisou fazer uma alteração. Onde está "screen.height > screen.width" deve ser "screen.height < screen.width".

Comment: Essa flickada que o  bfavaretto deve ser resolvida com minha resposta. É uma cópia da do J. Bruni, porém ela com `Debounced Resize()`.

Answer (score 2):

Um adição a solução do J. Bruni, que está certa é que ocorre um problema que sempre ocorre com listeners em resize é que ele pode ser disparado muitas vezes por segundo e isso pode travar a tela em certos navegadores, em especial em desktop.

Em casos como este, é interessante usar `Debounced Resize()` que está descrito em http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

```
// Plugin. Precisa ser adicionado apenas uma vez
(function($,sr){

  // debouncing function from John Hann
  // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
  var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
      var timeout;

      return function debounced () {
          var obj = this, args = arguments;
          function delayed () {
              if (!execAsap)
                  func.apply(obj, args);
              timeout = null;
          };

          if (timeout)
              clearTimeout(timeout);
          else if (execAsap)
              func.apply(obj, args);

          timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
      };
  }
  // smartresize 
  jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'smartresize');

// Uso do plugin smartresize com a solução de J. Bruni
$(window).smartresize(function(){
  if (screen.height > screen.width) {
    $('body').addClass('virado');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('virado');
  }
});
```

O código em CSS fica o mesmo

```
.virado {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```